# DML Operation on List<SObjects> - Where I got the record ID of various objects

Tags: apex, dynamic-dml

Scenario: I got a VF Page where I will get only `ID's` of various Objects, I wouldn't know which Object `RecordID` I would be getting in an instance. I need to update that record with that ID. Without knowing which Object, I can't create an instance of that object to update.

I need to update that list, where Objects could be of any type Accounts, Contacts Or any Custom Object.

Please advise, How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate an `sObject` record from an `Id` without knowing its type.

```
SObject record = someId.getSObjectType().newInstance(someId);
```

As already mentioned by Tushar, you can mix types in your operation, up to 10 types. You could do something like the following to flexibly support an arbitrary number of objects. It's just a sketch of what you need to implement; obviously you will have to test it and tweak to suit your needs. You may want to add some governor protections and other safeguards.

```
public dynamicUpdate(Set<Id> recordIds)
{
    Map<SObjectType, Set<Id>> objects = new Map<SObjectType, Set<Id>>();
    for (Id recordId : recordIds)
    {
        SObjectType idType = recordId.getSObjectType();
        if (!objects.contains(idType))
            objects.put(idType, new Set<Id>());
        objects.get(idType).add(recordId);
    }

    Integer typeCount = 0;
    List<SObject> records = new List<SObject>();
    for (SObjectType sObjectType : objects)
    {
        typeCount++
        for (Id recordId : objects.get(sObjectType))
            records.add(recordId.getSObjectType().newInstance(recordId));
        if (typeCount == 10)
        {
            update records;
            records.clear();
            typeCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create `List<sObject>` and update that. But there is few limit as well.

```
public static void dataSetup(){
   List<sObject> allObjects = new List<sObject>();
   allObjects.add(new Foo__c());
   allObjects.add(new Foo__c());
   allObjects.add(new Foo__c());
   allObjects.add(new Widget__c());
   allObjects.add(new Widget__c());
   allObjects.add(new Widget__c());
   allObjects.add(new Stub__c());
   allObjects.add(new Stub__c());
   allObjects.add(new Stub__c());
   insert allObjects;
}
```

**There is also a cap of 10 object types being mixed together.** Also some sObject can't be mixed with each other you need to handle that.

[Conserve DML Statements](http://jessealtman.com/2013/08/conserve-dml-statements/)

To handle the 10 object limit you can create a `map<string, List<sobject>>` and `key` store object name and in `value` make list of sobjects records.. Now once you complete the data processing. You can easily perform DML on this. You can break this in set of 10 easily.

Comment: Object on which DML operation is going to occur could be any Object in my Org(standard/custom). There are about 50+ in my org.

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar then you need to break them in multiple list. You can get Object Name from record Id using `String sObjName = myId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();`

Comment: This way I could get the Object Name, but how I could update this Object without initiating in apex.
That is sObjName - I would get the Object Name dynamically, But I should have initiated it in my apex so that I can Update it.

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar a basic idea here would be create `map<string, List<sobject>> ` and key store object name and in value make list of objects. Now once you complete the data processing. You can easily perform dml on this.